# Windows Logstash output to AWS SQS with IAM EC2 Role "Unable to access SQS queue"

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-server-2008, logstash, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I feel like I'm missing something here as nobody on the Interwebs seems to be having any issues. I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 EC2 instance setup with an IAM Role that allows `sqs:SendMessage`. I successfully sent a message on the command line using the AWS CLI and the command `aws sqs send-message`. When I attempt to use Logstash-1.4.2 I get the following error:

```
Unable to access SQS queue 'Dev-ELK-LogstashBuffer': The specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it. {:level=>:error}
Failed to flush outgoing items {:outgoing_count=>1, :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `batch_send' for nil:NilClass>, :backtrace=>
["C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/sqs.rb:131:in `flush'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in `buffer_flush'", 
"org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1339:in `each'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `buffer_flush'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.17/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in `buffer_receive'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/sqs.rb:123:in `receive'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:86:in `handle'", 
"(eval):129:in `initialize'", 
"org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:266:in `output'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:225:in `outputworker'", 
"C:/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152:in `start_outputs'"], 
:level=>:warn}
```

Here's my output configuration for logstash:

```
output {
    sqs {
        queue => "Dev-ELK-LogstashBuffer"
        region  => "us-west-2"
        use_ssl => true
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am able to use elasticsearch output directly but trying to add the message queue buffer between my servers and the elasticsearch cluster.

Thanks!

Comment: The IAM profile information is checked last according to the documentation page. Perhaps one of the other methods (eg credentials file) is being read first? Doc: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/sqs

Comment: I double-checked everything again and realized that I was misunderstanding the documentation when it was referring to the "consumer" policies. I thought it meant the logstash reading the queue and not the logstash sending to the queue. Added the policy actions (minus the non-existent *Batch ones) and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct IAM policy:

```
{
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:1111111:Dev-ELK-LogstashBuffer"
            ],
            "Action":[
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility"
            ],
            "Effect":"Allow"
        }
    ],
    "Version":"2012-10-17"
}
```